# Why is multithreaded quicksort slower than singlethreaded in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, quicksort

I know this question has been asked before, and the answers I found were all about the pre-empting & synchronization overhead etc.. But still, I am curious to know the answer of my own situation. So here's the deal.

I am running on [Intel Core i7-2670QM CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/53469/Intel-Core-i7-2670QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) (4 cores, 8 threads) and I wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace _T
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void stquicksort(object parameter)
        {
            object[] parameters = (object[])parameter;

            int[] array = (int[])parameters[0];
            int left = (int)parameters[1];
            int right = (int)parameters[2];

            if (left >= right) return;

            int temp = (left + right) / 2;
            int pivot = array[temp];

            array[temp] = array[right];

            int j = left;
            for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] < pivot)
                {
                    if (i != j)
                    {
                        temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j++] = temp;
                    }
                    else j++;
                }
            }

            array[right] = array[j];
            array[j] = pivot;

            stquicksort(new object[] { array, left, j - 1 });
            stquicksort(new object[] { array, j + 1, right });
        }
        private static void mtquicksort(object parameter)
        {
            object[] parameters = (object[])parameter;

            int[] array = (int[])parameters[0];
            int left = (int)parameters[1];
            int right = (int)parameters[2];

            if (left >= right) return;

            int temp = (left + right) / 2;
            int pivot = array[temp];

            array[temp] = array[right];

            int j = left;
            for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] < pivot)
                {
                    if (i != j)
                    {
                        temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j++] = temp;
                    }
                    else j++;
                }
            }

            array[right] = array[j];
            array[j] = pivot;

            Thread t = new Thread(mtquicksort);
            t.Start(new object[] { array, left, j - 1 });
            mtquicksort(new object[] { array, j + 1, right });
            t.Join();
        }

        private static void dump(int[] array)
        {
            Console.Write("Array:");
            foreach (int el in array) Console.Write(" " + el);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the number of elements: ");
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (count < 0) break;

                Random rnd = new Random();

                int[] array1 = new int[count];
                for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
                    array1[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                int[] array2 = (int[])array1.Clone();

                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

                sw.Reset(); sw.Start();
                stquicksort(new object[] { array1, 0, array1.Length - 1 });
                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("[ST] Time needed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

                sw.Reset(); sw.Start();
                mtquicksort(new object[] { array2, 0, array2.Length - 1 });
                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("[MT] Time needed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit . . .");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The stquicksort is the single threaded, mtquicksort is the multi one, and yes, I left the st parameters that way on purpose so the boxing/unboxing overheads are the same on both versions (if any noticable). I've put the solution on release (disabled all debugging), and the output is somewhat sad:

```
Enter the number of elements: 100  
[ST] Time needed: 0ms  
[MT] Time needed: 323ms  

Enter the number of elements: 1000  
[ST] Time needed: 0ms  
[MT] Time needed: 7476ms  

Enter the number of elements: 1000  
[ST] Time needed: 0ms  
[MT] Time needed: 7804ms  

Enter the number of elements: 1000  
[ST] Time needed: 0ms  
[MT] Time needed: 7474ms  

Enter the number of elements: 10  
[ST] Time needed: 0ms  
[MT] Time needed: 32ms  

Enter the number of elements: 100  
[ST] Time needed: 0ms  
[MT] Time needed: 339ms
```

So again, is the problem pre-empting, is it maybe a flaw in code? And more importantly, what would be a proper way to solve this.

Comment: why not work out the cost of threading independent of your quicksort..... you can answer your own question

Comment: @KeithNicholas Sure, I am fiddling with it rn, but wanned to hear some other suggestions & opinions, and on this concrete situation:)

Comment: You should try sorting more elements, like 1M, 10M, 100M

Comment: @Jason Tried, async/await & tasks actually cause stackoverflow, while with threads it is still very very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawning threads is a fairly expensive operation. It's not instantaneous so the massive time you are seeing is not additional time required to perform the sort but the time required to spawn the treads. When you spawn a new thread in order for it to be worth it that thread has to run for a while.

.NET and C# do have a Task system Task's are similar to threads except they operate on a thread pool instead of spawning a new thread every time. This allows you to multi thread tasks without the high cost of creating a new thread for each one.

Try replacing your threading code with this.

```
Task t = Task.Run(()=>mtquicksort(new object[] { array, left, j - 1 }));
t.Wait();
```

Note you will have to use the System.Threading.Tasks namespace

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've tried with tasks and yes they proved faster but still the single threaded seems faster. Thanks again :)

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help! 

Tasks are probably still slower for 2 reasons firstly they aren't cost free and your spawning (n log n) of them.

Also in order to fully take advantage of the task system you have to use the async and await syntax. Although you still might not get a performance boost.

Comment: Yes yes, I know the complexity but still wasn't expecting this to happen. Anyway, Async/Await is actually the next thing I wanned to try hehe, again thanks. :)